# Redirect When Sql Condition Match

Tags: php, sql

I want to redirect to different page when condition match or condition not match. i am taking one field Process in database with value "yes" . and want to redirect when two condition match, one is appid and one is process value="yes" . using below code its only redirecting to else condition header only even conditions found in database. what i am doing wrong here.

```
    <?php

$appid = $_GET['appid'];
$process = 'yes';

include("connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblapps WHERE app_id = '$appid' AND process = '$process'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    header("Location: disclaimer2.php?appid=".$appid);
} else {
    header("Location: modify/step2.php?appid=".$appid);
}

?>
```

Comment: use mysqli_num_rows if using mysqli api

Comment: @thanks to show me the error.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is below. Please use mysqli_* related functions please.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

if (count(resultArr) > 0) {
    header("Location: disclaimer2.php?appid=".$appid);
} else {
    header("Location: modify/step2.php?appid=".$appid);
}
```